# How to prove these inequalities

Tags: real-analysis

I'm stuck. Here is the defintions:

Define $h(x)=|x|$ on $[-1,1]$ and extend it to $\mathbb R$ by defining $h(2+x) = h(x)$. This is a sawtooth function that is $0$ at even and $1$ at odd integers.

Furthermore define $h_n(x) = (1/2)^n h(2^n x)$ and
$$ g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {1\over 2^n }h(2^n x) = \sum_{n \ge 0}h_n(x)$$

I showed that $g$ is defined everywhere and not differentiable at dyadic rationals.

Now I am trying to prove that if $g_m = h_0 + \dots + h_m$ and $x_m = {p \over 2^m} , y_m = {p+1 \over 2^m}$ where $p \in \mathbb Z$ then:

$$  {g(y_m) - g(x) \over y_m - x} < g'_m (x) < {g(x_m) - g(x) \over x_m - x}$$

But I can't do it. Please could somebody show me how to show the inequalities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have said that $x_m<x<y_m$.

Since $h$ vanishes at even integers, we have $h_n(p/2^m)=0$ whenever $p$ is an integer and $n>m$. Therefore, $g(y_m)=g_m(y_m)$ and $g(x_n)=g_m(x_m)$.

Also, every $h$ is nonnegative. And in your setup, $h_{m+1}(x)>0$. Hence $g(x)> g_m(x)$.

Finally, $g_m$ has constant slope between rationals of the form $p/2^m$ with integer $p$, because every $h_n $ with $n\le m$ has this property.

Put the above together: 
$${g(y_m) - g(x) \over y_m - x} < {g(y_m) - g_m(x) \over y_m - x} = g_m'(x) $$
and 
$${g(x_m) - g(x) \over x_m - x} > {g(x_m) - g_m(x) \over x_m - x} = g_m'(x) $$
In the second line $x_m-x<0$, which is why the inequality goes the opposite way.

Comment: Thank you. Why is ${g(y_m) - g_m(x) \over y_m - x} = g_m'(x)$? I don't understand.

Comment: $g'_m$ is a finite sum of $-1$ and $1$. No?